# How to export call history chat data from Skype

Tags: skype, export, skype-for-windows-10

I recently wanted to export all of my Skype chats / calls in order to be able to process them elsewhere (get some statistics on time spent calling, messages sent...).

However I found that most solutions on the web were outdated, and only allowed me to recover old chats, and nothing from last year on. Including nirsoft's skype log viewer, opening main.db...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no way to export them form the Desktop/win32 app. However there's a way with the app from the Microsoft store: download the Skype app from the Microsoft App Store (not the win32 version), log in and wait for it to sync all the data. The sqlite .db file you want is:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c\LocalState\xxx-yourskypeusername.db
```

Where: `xxx` is (in my case) 3 characters and numbers, and `youskypeusername` is your skype username.

Open with any SQLLite viewer, the table you want is `messagesv12`. There are stored all messages as well as calls, with their date duration, and all info.